# Get the average for a set of records

Tags: mysql, average

I have a table of reviews for campsites that have categories (Price, View, facilities, location).
The following query is used to show the top 20 reviews by average of the four categories.

```
SELECT
  ROUND(((R.price + R.location + R.facilities + R.view) / 4), 2) AS avg,
  R.poi_id,
  poi.Name
FROM
  `Reviews` AS `R`
  LEFT JOIN `poi` ON `R`.`poi_id` = `poi`.`ID`
ORDER BY avg DESC
LIMIT 20
```

However I have realised the query does not accomodate scenarios where there are more than one review for the same campsite.

So is there a query that would return the highest 20 rated campsite(poi) with an average of price,view,facilities,location/number of reviews for that poiID?

Answer (score 0):

The average function is of course to cumulative, but you can implement it yourself by `SUM`ing the review scores and `COUNT`ing their numbers:

```
SELECT
  ROUND(((R.price + R.location + R.facilities + R.view) / 4 * cnt), 2) AS avg,
  R.poi_id,
  poi.Name
FROM
  (SELECT SUM(price) AS price, 
          SUM(location) AS location,
          SUM(facilities) AS facilities,
          SUM(view) AS view,
          COUNT(*) AS cnt,
          poi_id
   FROM   Review
   GROUP BY poi_id) AS `R`
  LEFT JOIN `poi` ON `R`.`poi_id` = `poi`.`ID`
ORDER BY avg DESC
LIMIT 20
```